# How to enable user three attempt to enter the right password?

Tags: java

Thanks in advance!

I am looking for a simple piece of code which will ask user to input a value.

If the value is >= 100 then it accept is and complete the program, Else it will prompt user its invalid entry and ask to retry again . User will have 3 chances to provide the valid input

Comment: The answer is, it depends. Is it a console/gui/android/web app?

Comment: Just a simple java program for practicing buddy

Answer (score 2):

the question you have asked can be easily implemented, just use if condition for checking the input if true then proceed else call the login function again. If true then use a variable to store the number of incorrect attempts and if this value increases by 3 then block the user and send him the authentication mail.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this with counter variable.

```
    int count = 0;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    while (count < 3) {
        System.out.println("Enter value");
        int input = sc.nextInt();
        ++count;
        if (input >= 100) {
            System.out.println("Success");
            break;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Re-enter");
        }
    }

    sc.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
static void main (String args [])
{
     boolean isValuevalid = false;
     Snanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

     for(int i =0; isValuevalid == false; i++ )
     {
         System.out.println("Attempt #" + (i + 1) + "/3");
         System.out.println("Enter value: ");

         int value = scanner.nextInt();

         if( i == 3 ) System.out.println("Maximum attempt reached sorry.");

         else if( value >= 100 ) isValuevalid = true;

         else System.out.println("Try again!");
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try some thing like this

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        int count = 0;
        int i = 0;
        while (count < 4) {
            i = s.nextInt();

            if (i >= 100) {
                System.out.println("Value accepted");
                count = 4;

            } else {
                System.out.println("Entered value is invalid retry again");
                System.out.println("Enter new value:");

                count++;
            }

        }
```

Comment: how are you going to implement the program @Vijay Balaji. is it a console application or desktop app??

Comment: Its a simple java program for practicing !

Comment: Man! You are damn cool, Thanks a lot, I got it in a easy understandable way :) :) Thanks a ton :),

Comment: ah..then its OK. But when your asking questions here you need to show your attempt.if not question will be closed.

Comment: nice to here that @Vijay Balaj.Its good to help you :):) .If you got the answer please accept it.

Comment: Oops sorry, Total newbie here!